# Xcode5 project for iOS7 and iOS6 has different app size on a iPhone5 and autolayout

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5

I'm working on a project which was new created in Xcode5-DP3. When I run the app on a 4-inch iOS7 device (hardware or simulator), the app comes up with a expected size of 640 x 1136 pixel. When I run the same project on iOS6 4-inch device or in the simulator, the app runs with a screen size of 640 x 960 pixel and the old black borders top and buttom of the screen.

Another app which was migrated from Xcode 4.6.3 to Xcode5-DP3 runs in the expected screen size of 640 x 1136 pixels. So I guess there is a property which controls this behavior.

There is one difference between the apps. All apps which run with the full size have an autosizing storyboard but the app with wrong size is my first app with an autolayouting storyboard.

Does anyone know which parameter is responsible for this?

Thanks and regards,
Thomas

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1 this link might help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the reason for this behavior and it is not related to Xcode5.

Since Xcode4 the 4-inch iPhone 5 screen is supported and you have to build your apps for this device as well. To identify whether a app is supporting this screen resolution, you have to set a launch image for 1x, @2x (Retina 3.5 inch) and R4 (Retina 4 inch). If you don't, the app starts with the black bar top and button.

I added this images to my project and the app starts with the expected full 4-inch size. You have to do this in manually in Xcode5 because it is not maintained by default (iPhone Portrait iOS 5, 6).